# Determinate a normal versos for the surface.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Determinate a normal versor for the surface $S$ in $\Bbb R^3$ with global parametrization $\varphi:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ given by $\varphi(u,v)=(e^u,u+v,u)$, and compute the angle betweem the coordinate curves.

**Try:**
I understand that a versor is a unit vector, so to find the versor I have a formula which is, $$N=\dfrac{\varphi_u\times \varphi_v}{|\varphi_u\times\varphi_v|}$$

I find all that and I have my vector. But I don't know how to compute the angle between the coordinate curves, I don't have a formula for that, could someone help me.

Comment: Do you have a formula for the angle between two vectors in $\Bbb R^3$? Perhaps you should try using that.

Comment: In a book I found that the cosine of the angle between the coordinate curves is $\cos\theta=\dfrac{F}{\sqrt{EG}}$, from there you can solve the angle, if that formula is correct? @TedShifrin

Comment: You need to understand things, not just plug into formulas you don’t understand.